# Proof via vector algebra that kinetic energy remains constant when a force acts perpedicularly to velocity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation, vectors

Given:

- Initial speed $$v_{\text{initial}} = k \space \text{m/s}$$ in the positive x-direction $$\hat{i}$$
- Applied force $$\mathbf{F} = n \, \text{N} $$ in the positive y-direction $$\hat{j}$$
- $$ Mass =   m \space \text{kg} $$

If this force is applied to the particle, I feel that the resultant velocity would have both i and j components, and so speed **cannot** remain constant

but since the force is perpendicular and no work is done, speed cannot change. I would like to see this solution work out vectorally so I see where I'm going wrong.

Comment: If this force is constantly applied then obviously it will stop being perpendicular and then the speed can change. You need a force that is perpendicular to the velocity at all times for the speed to stay constant.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent I'm referring to a one time application of the force though.

Comment: You mean for one instant? Are you sure it is a finite force and not infinite force, i.e. a one-instant finite impulse? Forces are such things that "one time" does not make sense for them.

Comment: I could be wrong here, just trying to understand how this would work. What is the right way to think about this then? 
 adding a force along the y axis to a particle moving along the x axis with speed v_x should result in v_x + something*v_y  (since the force is along the y axis) which means the kinetic energy should change since speed now has two components
but since W = FdCos(theta) and the angle is 90, W is zero and the kinetic energy should remain constant
Im trying to reconcile these two ideas

Comment: There is displacement in the y direction.

Comment: That's the thing, you cannot apply a force at one instant and no more.

Answer (score 2):

The force has to last some $\Delta t$ so $v_y=\frac{F}{m}*\Delta t, s_y=a/2*t^2$
so Sped is not constant, but also you have Work $F\cdot s_y$